# Java string to Int

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I have a string with about 150 numbers like this String num = "64513246563........";

I am trying to add each digit of this string. So my idea was to split it into an array of ints and add them from there. I start by splitting it into a String array, then I try to convert it to an Int array. I get an unknown source error. Below is the code:

```
String[] strArray = num.split("");
int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
           intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
           }
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

////////////////////////////////

Thanks for your help everyone, it seems that splitting a string using .split("") creates an empty string at index 0. That was my main problem but there was lots of useful pointers on how to solve the problem more efficiently :) Thank you all for your input

Comment: print strArray[i] in each iteration of the loop and see what it prints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    sum += Character.getNumericValue(string.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: You need `num.length()` instead of `num.length`.

Comment: You changed it quickly :P But you first wrote `Integer.parseInt(num.charAt(i))`.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I knew it at the time I send the answer so I changed it immediately :)

Comment: Thanks Tomas, this is what I eventually used to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 8):

The first string given by `num.split("");` is empty.

A solution is to simply start the iteration at index 1.

But what you do is much too expensive as you could do

```
    String num = "64513246563";
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
         int digit = num.charAt(i)-'0';
         ... // use the digit, perhaps adding it
    }
```

Comment: `+1` for showing why the empty string was there to begin with.

Comment: Exactly, I wasn't sure how I was getting an empty String. +1 and thank you for that explanation.

Comment: @shanahobo86 If this is for more than just learning, I seriously recommend you not building your intermediate array and all those strings you parse. This is really wasteful.

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

exception message clearly telling that input is empty String.

One way to handle would be, do empty `String` check before parsing.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length(); i++) {
           if(strArray[i] != null && !"".equals(strArray[i])
              {
               int q = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
              }
           }
```

Note: This will still fail if input is not valid int, but not in case of empty String (or) null.

Another way to handle this would be get `chartAt(i)` instead of using `split("")`

Comment: This is great thanks for your help. I'm not sure how the String could be empty but this certainly handles the issue. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @shanahobo86 you can start i from 1 not zero check my answer.

Comment: @shanahobo86 Note that you will have a 0 at your 0th element in your array with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
String num="12234";
        String[] numarr = num.split("");
        System.out.println(numarr.length);
```

When you split a string with `""` there will be an **empty string** at the zeroth index. 
Thus your resulting array would be :

```
{"", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4"}
```

test it, the above returns the length as 6. thus `Integer.parseInt("")` leads to **NumberFormatException**.

Test:

```
String num="12234";
        String[] numarr = num.split("");
        for(String s: numarr){
            if(s.equals("")){
                System.out.println("empty string");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
```

Output:

```
empty string
1
2
2
3
4
```

Thus, there is an emptyString at index 0.

so, you will have to check if the String is an empty string before parsing it:

```
String[] strArray = num.split("");
int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
           if(!strArray[i].equals(""))
           intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
           }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I won't make the same mistake again:) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] charArray = num.toCharArray();

for(char c : charArray) {
    int q = Integer.parseInt("" + c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<yourString.length; i++) {
    yourIntegers[i] = Integer.parseInt(yourString.charAt(i).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply step along the string, parsing each digit:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); ++i) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(num.substring(i, i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since array start from a empty string you have to skip first element hence Start `i` from `1` in your for loop.

```
for(int i = 1; i < strArray.length; i++)
```

Comment: A rationale would improve this answer.